# Can someone please explain me the logic of this python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

This is a python code which is used for getting the square roots of numbers.
Plz explain the logic behind this?

```
x = int(input('ENTER A NO:- '))
epsilon = 0.1
numGusses=0
low = 0.0
high = max(1.0,x)
ans = (high+low)/2.0
while abs(ans**2 - x) >= epsilon:
    print('low =',low,'high =',high,'ans =',ans)
    numGusses+=1
    if ans**2 < x:
        low = ans
    else:
        high = ans
    ans = (high+low)/2.0
print('numGuesses =',numGusses)
print(ans,'is close to the square root of',x)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  You've asked for an open-ended tutorial.

Comment: Instead, show your work to trace the program's logic.  Ask a *specific* question where you got lost.

Answer (score 0):

This code finds an approximation to a square root by setting a high and low bound and then making a "guess" that's right in the middle.

Test how good the guess was by squaring it and comparing it to the input.

If the guess was high, that's the new high bound; if it was low, that's the new low bound.

Repeat (making a new guess that's in the middle of the new range) until the guess is "close enough".

An easier way to understand what this code is doing is just to run it.  It outputs lots of debugging information (including the high/low bounds for each iteration) so it's very easy to visualize what it's doing.